# Virtual Inheritance, one class enough?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance

I understand the concept of virtual inheritance, but I couldn't find the answer to this anywhere. Say you have class D which inherits class B and C. Both B and C inherit class A. So you could make B and C virtually inherit A to avoid two instances of A. But do you have to specify virtual inheritance at both B and C or does it already create only one instance of A if one of the two virtually inherits A and the other doesn't?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They must all be `virtual`. From C++11 10.1 [class.mi]/7:

A class can have both virtual and non-virtual base classes of a given type.

```
class B { /* ... */ };
class X : virtual public B { /* ... */ };
class Y : virtual public B { /* ... */ };
class Z : public B { /* ... */ };
class AA : public X, public Y, public Z { /* ... */ };
```

For an object of class `AA`, all virtual occurrences of base class `B` in the class lattice of `AA` correspond to a single `B` subobject within the object of type `AA`, and every other occurrence of a (non-virtual) base class `B` in the class lattice of `AA` corresponds one-to-one with a distinct `B` subobject within the object of type `AA`. Given the class `AA` defined above, class `AA` has two subobjects of class `B`: `Z`’s `B` and the virtual `B` shared by `X` and `Y`, as shown below.

[image: virtual inheritance example]

Comment: Also, §10.1/4 actually defines this.

Comment: @sftrabbit: In what copy of the standard? In C++03, it is `10.1 [class.mi]/6`; in the latest available working paper, N3485, it is still `10.1 [class.mi]/7`. I don't have any standard copies where it is defined in `10.1 [class.mi]/4`.

Comment: I've always wondered why they didn't allow what OP is asking though. I don't see any logical obstacle to the virtual child pointing to the parent of the non-virtual child.

Comment: @BillyONeal Apologies. What I meant is that 10.1/4 (in C++11) defines how many copies of the base class appear in the derived class, whereas your paragraph is an example of it occurring. :)

Comment: @enobayram: Because class `Z` in the above example may have invariants that assume that it has its own copy of class `B`. If a class is designed for virtual inheritance, its code must reflect that other classes may change its underlying copy of any virtually inherited members.

Comment: @BillyONeal Ah, good point, thanks. Though unless class `Z` is inheriting privately, it's already putting its invariants in similar danger.

Comment: @enobayram: Maybe, maybe not. Depends on what class `B`'s member functions do :)

Comment: I see, thanks for a thorough explanation! Also, I'm wondering, if B only inherits A, and A inherits some other class virtually, could this cause a performance penalty? As in, would it be faster to not virtually inherit at A?

Comment: @Invalid: Virtual inheritance always has a perf penalty.

Answer (score 9):

You need to specify virtual inheritance for both B and C to have one A. Otherwise the class that is not using virtual inheritance will "share" class A.

This can enable one to have the following:

[image: inheritance]

Why you want to do this is another matter.

Comment: Sadly I can only accept one answer, thanks for the explanation though ;)

Comment: I'm giving +1 for the hand-drawn and scanned-in diagram.