# Memory allocation for multiple inheritance with non-default constructors

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, diamond-problem

I'm struggling a bit to understand multiple-inheritance. Apparently I chose to solve a very complicated problem that has multiple inheritance and also the diamond problem. Even if I I have found a couple of cases that are similar to my problem, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27457101/sequence-of-constructor-calls-in-multiple-inheritance), my question is is on memory more than order of execution.

Suppose I have the following:

```
class Matrix {
public:
  Matrix(int rows, int Cols) {
    // Build matrix of zeros
  }
};

class Symmetric : public virtual Matrix {
public:
  // It's enough to call Matrix constructor using the same number of rows and cols
  Symmetric(int size) : Matrix(size, size) {}
};

class PosDef : public virtual Matrix {
public:
  // We need different constructor, matrix of zeros is not pos def
  PosDef(int size) {
    // Build matrix of ones
  }
};

class SymmPosDef : public Symmetric, public PosDef {
public:
  // We basically want to use the PosDef constructor that gives symmetric matrix
  SymmPosDef(int size) : Matrix(size, size), Symmetric(size), PosDef(size) {}
};
```

Because I have given non-default constructors the only way to initialise a `SymmPosDef` object is with the complicated chain `SymmPosDef(int size) : Matrix(size, size), Symmetric(size), PosDef(size) {}` and my question is how many matrices am I building?

Am I allocating space once for `Matrix`, once for `Symmetric` (which would be the same zero elements) and once for `PosDef` or am I reusing the same space?

Because the size of the matrices could be large I want to do the least possible work.

Comment: Don't use multiple inheritance.

Comment: @RawN Any suggestions to handle the relationships of symmetry and positive-definiteness then?

Comment: I would say free functions and composition.

Comment: Look at [Circle-ellipse_problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem) first to see that simple inheritance is already wrong in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Matrix` is initialized (from initalizer list) only once, in the most derived class.
But all constructor **body** will be called.

With:

```
class SymmPosDef : public Symmetric, public PosDef {
public:
  SymmPosDef(int size) : Matrix(size, size), Symmetric(size), PosDef(size) {}
};
```

You would have:

- `Matrix(size, size)`
- (`Symmetric(int size) : Matrix(size, size)` skipped)
- `Symmetric(int size)` body (`/*Empty*/`).
- (`PosDef(int size) : Matrix(size, size`) skipped)
- `PosDef(int size)` body ( `/* Build matrix of ones */` )
- `SymmPosDef(int size)` body (`/*Empty*/`).