# virtual inheritance in c++ order of inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class BaseClass_1 {
  public:
    BaseClass_1()
    {
      cout << "you are in  baseclass 1" << endl;
    }
};

class BaseClass_2 {
  public:
    BaseClass_2()
    {
      cout << "you are in baseclass 2" << endl;
    }
};

class Derived_class: public  BaseClass_1, public  BaseClass_2 {
    
    public:
    Derived_class(){
               cout<< "you are in derived class ";
    }
 
};

int main(){
    Derived_class  d;
    return 0;
}
```

with this code output is :
you are in  baseclass 1
you are in baseclass 2
you are in derived class

as the constructors are called from base class in the order in which they are written

```
class Derived_class: public  BaseClass_1, public  BaseClass_2
```

if i change this line to

```
  class Derived_class: public  BaseClass_1,public virtual BaseClass_2
```

we get output as:
you are in baseclass 2
you are in  baseclass 1
you are in derived class

so the base class 2 constructor is called first,
the order is altered , how this happens?

Comment: Because the standard says so... Virtual base classes are always constructed first.

Comment: Virtual base classes are always constructed first---- why so?

Comment: [Because the standard says so!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27457219)